# Codility excercise: Fish

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Task**:N voracious fish are moving along a river. Calculate how many fish are alive. [Here is description of exercise.](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/fish/). 
I use javascript, My code is as follows:

```
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// console.log('this is a debug message');

//fish
function solution(fishSize, fishDirection)
{
    var arr = [];
    // arr.push({size: fishSize[0], direction: fishDirection[0]});
    // for(let i = 1; i < fishSize.length; i++)
    // {
    //     pushNewFish(arr, fishSize[i], fishDirection[i]);
    // }
    for (let i = fishSize.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        pushNewFish(arr, fishSize[i], fishDirection[i]);
    }

    return arr.length;
}

function pushNewFish(arr, fishSize, fishDirection)
{
    // if(arr.length > 0 && fishDirection != arr[arr.length - 1].fishDirection && fishSize != arr[arr.length - 1].fishSize)
    if(arr.length > 0 && arr[arr.length - 1].fishDirection === 0 && fishDirection === 1 && fishSize != arr[arr.length - 1].fishSize)
    {
        // while(arr.length > 0 && arr[arr.length - 1].fishDirection != fishDirection)
        while(arr.length > 0 && arr[arr.length - 1].fishDirection === 0 && fishDirection === 1)
        {
            if (arr[arr.length - 1].fishSize < fishSize)
            {
                arr.pop();
            }
            else 
            {
                if(arr[arr.length - 1].fishSize === fishSize)
                {
                    arr.push({fishSize, fishDirection});
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (arr.length == 0) arr.push({fishSize, fishDirection});
    }
    else 
    {
        arr.push({fishSize: fishSize, fishDirection: fishDirection});
    }
}
```

My code gets only 50% task score. I cannot understand why not all the tests are passed by my code.  Please help me find the error, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking for help on your homework?

Comment: @AdrianBrand It's not my homework. It's just daily practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
function solution(A, B) {
// write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
let stack=[];
 let c=B.length;
 for(let j=0;j<B.length;j++){
   if(B[j]===1){
     stack.push(A[j]);
   }
   else if(B[j]===0){
    while(stack.length>0){
        if(stack[stack.length-1]>A[j]){
           c=c-1;
          break;
        }else if(stack[stack.length-1]<A[j]){
           c=c-1;
          stack.pop();
        }
    }
   }
 }
 return c;
}
```

Comment: My code gets 100% score in Javascript and complexity is O(N)

Comment: Probably you should also mention what's wrong in the original code in the question. That will help them understand what are the things that make a code run faster and accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript 100%

```
function solution(a, b) {
    if (a.length === 1) {
    return 1;
}

if (new Set(b).size === 1) return b.length;

const stayAlive = [0];

for (let i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    stayAlive.push(i);

    if (b[stayAlive[i - 1]] <= b[stayAlive[i]]) continue;

    while (b[stayAlive[stayAlive.length - 2]] > b[stayAlive[stayAlive.length - 1]]) {
        stayAlive.pop();

        if (a[stayAlive[stayAlive.length - 1]] < a[i]) {
            stayAlive[stayAlive.length - 1] = i;
        }
    }
}

return stayAlive.length;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please don't post code-only answers.  Please [edit] to add some context and explanations.